# Grouping 3 columns into 1 column

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL so maybe this question is so basic or maybe it can't be done. Can I group 3 columns into 1 column in SQL Server?

It goes something like this

```
 WorkLoc    Status           Total_Employee
                       Total      Man    Woman
Malaysia | FullTime | 3       | 2        | 1 | 
Malaysia | Contract | 2       | 2        |   |
```

All 3 columns (WorkLoc, Status, and Total_Employee) are in 3 different tables

Comment: In what context? Are you running a query and you want to concatenate the contents of three columns?

Comment: Not very clear...... what are you trying to accomplish?? Do you want to select from your table, and combine three columns into one for the result of that select? If so: what **datatypes** are these columns? How do you want to combine them - separated by some delimiter, or just concatenated together??

Comment: Hilman from this 3 column what is your expected result

Comment: Im sorry if my question is kinda hard to understand. So basically i have a table that contains employees data and i have to make a report using join. But 1 of the column 3 data, its goes like this

  Total Employee
Total | Man | Woman

im sorry im new to stackoverflow also

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add 3 columns by using `CONCAT` you can do that

```
select WorkLoc,status,Total, concat(totalman,totalwomen) as totalemployee from yourtable
```

Comment: So the column is employee gender, and i want to generate to table. 
1st column is WorkLocation
2nd column is Status
3rd column is Total Employee but this 3rd column contains Total, Man, and Woman in number format, ex:
WorkLocation = Indonesia
Status = Full
TotEmp:
Total = 3
Man = 1
Woman = 2
@Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo you have to generate separately total man ,women then need to concat those values its easy

Answer (score 0):

[About CONCAT Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT CONCAT( name, middlename, lastname ) AS Result  
FROM Table
```

And in case there are Null values you can you this.

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL {ON|OFF}
```

With a seperator;

```
 SELECT CONCAT( '-', name, middlename, lastname) AS Result  
    FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column 1 As Title 1, Column 2 As Title 2, CONCAT( Column A , Column B,  Column C) AS title
FROM Table
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017](http://CONCAT_WS)